Move row to the end of the data automatically when a cell changes
I have a data set where column C is M for members and N for non-members. I am trying to create a macro/VBA where if a M is typed nothing happens but if an M is changed to an N the row moves to the end of the data set and if an N is changed to an M it moves back up. The data set is always being added to so I'm also not sure if its possible to do it with a range of basically the whole book or if it needs a set range. I'm very new to this so the more detailed the explanation the better.
I tried using VBA's found through videos but none of them were doing what I wanted them to do.
Here is sample data:



Name
DOB
Member/Non




Nell Dugan
May 17, 2000
M


Michele Joyce
Sep. 18, 1982
N


Elizabeth Cassidy
Sep. 30, 2000
N


Brandi Riggs
Jul. 24, 1982
M


Flora Greer
Oct. 23, 1997
N


Patty Pearson
Jun. 16, 1984
M


Julio Boyd
Aug. 7, 1983
N


Marilyn Strickland
Jun. 9, 1983
N


Mona Hurley
Oct. 2, 1991
M


Dan Phelps
Nov. 5, 2002
N


Hope Jordan
Oct. 16, 2000
M


Austin Benjamin
Aug. 5, 1992
N


Robbie Reyes
Jul. 27, 1997
N


Muriel Carson
Jul. 15, 1981
N


Spencer McIntyre
Mar. 13, 1989
M


Warren Cardenas
Jan. 4, 1988
M


Kristen Salinas
Mar. 25, 2003
N


Oscar Love
Apr. 19, 1987
M


Meghan Moran
Jul. 25, 1993
M


Claudia Garner
Feb. 15, 2001
M



and a code I tried using from was:
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim memberColumn As Long
    Dim cell As Range
    
    ' Set reference to the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Reference to "Sheet1"
    
    ' Define the column number for "Member" (Assuming "Member" is in Column C, which is column 3)
    memberColumn = 3 ' Column C is column 3, update if "Member" is in another column
    
    ' Check if the change happened in any cell in the worksheet
    If Not Intersect(Target, ws.UsedRange) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False ' Disable events to prevent an infinite loop
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False ' Disable screen updating for performance
        
        ' Loop through all cells in the changed range
        For Each cell In Intersect(Target, ws.Columns(memberColumn))
            If cell.Row > 1 Then ' Skip the header row (assuming row 1 is the header)
                
                LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, memberColumn).End(xlUp).Row ' Find the last row with data in column C
                
                ' If the value in the "Member" column is "N"
                If cell.Value = "N" Then
                    ' Move the row to the bottom of the data set
                    ws.Rows(cell.Row).Cut
                    ws.Rows(LastRow + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown

                ' If the value in the "Member" column changes from "N" to "M"
                ElseIf cell.Value = "M" Then
                    ' Move the row back to the second row (just below the header)
                    ws.Rows(cell.Row).Cut
                    ws.Rows(2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' Re-enable events
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Re-enable screen updating
    End If
End Sub


The way to do it in VBA is by using the Worksheet Change event assuming the values in column C will change manually (not by formula) best by using a dropdown list. Could you share some relevant sample data using this Table to Markdown Generator so we have something to work with? Simply copy not more than 21 relevant rows (including the headers) of a table into the big text box, press Submit, press Copy and paste it into your post (question). Also, share at least one of the codes you have tried. Then we'il be able to answer.

I have a code for you. I have voted to reopen your question, but another two votes are necessary. In the meantime, feel free to download my working file from my Google Drive.

A Worksheet Change: Move Row to End (Beginning) of Group of Two

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    ' Define constants.
    Const TOP_TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "C2"
    Const TOP_STRING As String = "M"
    Const BOTTOM_STRING As String = "N"
    Const TOP_TO_START As Boolean = False
    Const BOTTOM_TO_START As Boolean = False
    
    ' Exit if multiple cells.
    If Target.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub

    ' Reference the worksheet.
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Me

    ' Reference the whole range.
    Dim srg As Range
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set srg = ws.Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells.CountLarge))
    End With

    ' Reference the intersection between the whole range and target range.
    Dim trg As Range
    With ws.Range(TOP_TARGET_CELL_ADDRESS)
        Set trg = Intersect(.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), srg)
    End With
    
    ' Exit if the column of the target range is out of bounds.
    If trg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    ' Reference the target cell.
    Dim tcell As Range: Set tcell = Intersect(trg, Target)
    ' Exit if no intersection between the target range and the target cell.
    If tcell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Retrieve the new (changed) string.
    Dim NewString As String: NewString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    ' Exit if it is neither.
    If NewString <> TOP_STRING And NewString <> BOTTOM_STRING Then Exit Sub

    ' Start error-handling routine before disabling events
    ' to ensure they get reenabled.
    Dim ErrorMessage As String, WasError As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ' Retrieve the old (initial) string.
    Application.Undo
    Dim OldString As String: OldString = CStr(tcell.Value)
    ' Exit (enabling events) if it isn't any required string,
    ' or is equal to the new string.
    If OldString <> TOP_STRING And OldString <> BOTTOM_STRING Then
        tcell.Value = NewString ' rewrite
        GoTo ProcExit
    End If
    If OldString = NewString Then GoTo ProcExit

    ' Retrieve the row and column of the target cell.
    Dim TargetRow As Long: TargetRow = tcell.Row
    Dim TargetColumn As Long: TargetColumn = tcell.Column
    
    ' Reference the whole new (changed) row.
    Dim trrg As Range: Set trrg = srg.Rows(TargetRow)

    ' Reference the insert (single-row) range.
    Dim irrg As Range, InsertRow As Long
    If NewString = TOP_STRING Then
        If TOP_TO_START Then
            InsertRow = trg.Row
        Else
            InsertRow = trg.Rows(Application.Match(BOTTOM_STRING, trg, 0)).Row
        End If
        With srg.Rows(InsertRow)
            .Insert xlShiftDown
            Set irrg = .Offset(-1)
        End With
    Else ' NewString = BOTTOM_STRING
        If BOTTOM_TO_START Then
            InsertRow = trg.Rows(Application.Match(BOTTOM_STRING, trg, 0)).Row
            With srg.Rows(InsertRow)
                .Insert xlShiftDown
                Set irrg = .Offset(-1)
            End With
        Else
            Set irrg = srg.Rows(srg.Rows.Count).Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
    
    ' Copy, rewrite the new string, and delete.
    trrg.Copy Destination:=irrg
    irrg.Columns(TargetColumn).Value = NewString
    trrg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp

ProcExit:
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        If WasError Then MsgBox ErrorMessage, vbCritical
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
ClearError:
    ErrorMessage = "Run-time error [" & Err.Number & "]:" & vbLf & vbLf _
        & Err.Description
    WasError = True
    Resume ProcExit
End Sub

Extra
' Have this close when developing code that disables events.
Sub EnableEvents()
    Debug.Print "Events had " _
        & IIf(Application.EnableEvents, "already", "not") & " been enabled."
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

